# hide sheet rows based on slicer selection

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, slicers

Is there any way to hide certain rows if a certain value in slicer is selected?
I have some plots that need to be shown only if one specific chain is selected, if it's not selected - then hide the plots (located in rows 287:345).
I tried following, but it didn't work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Chain").SlicerItems("ChainName").Selected = True Then
        Rows("287:346").Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("287:346").Hidden = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: you would want EntireRow.Hidden = True for starters i think. And i usually target the pivottable associated with the slicer but maybe that is just me i.e. the associated pivottable update event.

Comment: Also, instead of hard-coding row numbers, assign a named range in Excel and reference that named range in your code. Otherwise you need to adjust your VBA code any time you insert/delete rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Requirement:** To show\hide a `Range` of rows based on the `Selected` status of a `SlicerItem`.

**VBA Procedure:** *(as per OP approach)*

Try the following procedure *(see comments\explanation within the procedure)*:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Dim sc As SlicerCache, sl As Slicer
    Dim sPt As String, sFld As String, sItm As String, sRng As String

    'Use variables to hold the criteria to be applied
        sPt = "PivotTable1"
        sFld = "Chain"
        sItm = "A.6"
        sRng = "287:346"

        With Target

            Rem Validate PivotTable
            If .Name <> sPt Then Exit Sub

    ' As Slicer names can be easily changed by users, need to identify
    ' the SlicerCache connected to the target `PivotTable` using the 
    ' SourceName of the PivotField. This step returns the SlicerCache 
    ' connected to the PivotTable otherwise, the SlicerCache is nothing.
            Rem Set SlicerCache
            For Each sl In .Slicers
                If sl.SlicerCache.SourceName = sFld Then
                    Set sc = sl.SlicerCache
                    Exit For
        End If: Next: End With

        Rem Validate SlicerItem & Apply Result
        If Not (sc Is Nothing) Then

    ' This line Shows\Hides the target range based on the opposite 
    ' status of the target SlicerItem.
            Me.Rows(sRng).EntireRow.Hidden = Not (sc.SlicerItems(sItm).Selected)

        Else

    ' PivotTable is not connected to a Slicer of the target PivotField
            MsgBox "PivotTable [" & sPt & "]" & String(2, vbLf) & _
                vbTab & "is not connected to Slicer of Field [" & sFld & "].", _
                vbApplicationModal + vbInformation, "Slicers Selection"

        End If

        End Sub
```

**Another Aproach:**

Bear in mind that a `Slicer` is a kind of remote control of the `PivotTables` that works in both directions, i.e. the `Slicer` updates the `PivotTables` and the `PivotTables` update the `Slicer`, as such there is no need to validate if the `PivotTable` was updated by a `Slicer` operation, just need to check the `Visible` property of the target `PivotItem` in the target `PivotTable`, regardless of whether the `Slicer` and the `PivotTable` are connected or not.

This procedure only uses the target `PivotTable` i.e. shows or hides the target range, based on whether the `PivotItem` is visible or not in the PivotTable.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Dim sPt As String, sFld As String, sItm As String, sRng As String

        sPt = "PivotTable1"
        sFld = "Chain"
        sItm = "A.6"
        sRng = "287:346"

        With Target

            Rem Validate PivotTable
            If .Name <> sPt Then Exit Sub

            Rem Validate PivotItem & Apply Result
            With .PivotFields(sFld).PivotItems(sItm)
                Me.Rows(sRng).EntireRow.Hidden = Not (.Visible)

        End With: End With

        End Sub
```

Comment: The second approach worked perfectly for me, especially when I added some worksheet references and a condition checking if only one item is selected in the pivottable filter (turned out that I only want those plots if the specific chain is the only item selected)

Answer (score 1):

I would target the `Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate` event for the pivottable associated with the slicer.

**Location:**

In the code pane for the worksheet containing the pivottable associated with the slicer.

Something like as follows:

**Note:**

1. Change pivottable name as appropriate
2. If rows to hide are in a different sheet, add the worksheet name before the Rows, e.g.

   ```
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("287:346").EntireRow.Hidden = False
   ```

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

    If Target.Name <> "PivotTable1" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
       If Parent.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Chain").SlicerItems("ChainName").Selected Then
        Rows("287:346").EntireRow.Hidden = False
       Else
        Rows("287:346").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Good answer. Note that an awful lot of things trigger a PivotTable Update event, as outlined at my post at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/07/08/what-caused-that-pivottableupdate-part-two/ If required, you can check the undo stack and see if the update was caused by a Slicer Operation. Often when using the PivotTable_Update event I create a 'slave' Pivot with just the field of interest in it, and link it to the 'master' Pivot. Then I connect them with a hidden slicer, and use the update event from the Slave. This lets me harvest update events triggered by that field only.

Comment: @jeffreyweir Tell me more....I don't know much about such things tbh. I will have a look at that reference tomorrow. Is there an edit I should make to the above in the meantime to improve it? Something that might make the call less expensive.....

Comment: Your answer is great as is...my comment was intended merely for information in the case that someone is searching for a way to only run code when a *particular* PivotField is changed. :-)

Comment: The `hidden` property of the target rows will be updated repeatedly if the target worksheet contains other `PivotTables` with the same `PivotCache`. To avoid that separate the validation of the `PivotTable` name and the validation of the `PivotItem` selection by replacing this line:  `If Target.Name = "PivotTable1" And Parent.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Chain").SlicerItems("ChainName").Selected Then` with this two lines:
`If Target.Name <> "PivotTable1" then Exit Sub` and `If Parent.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Chain").SlicerItems("ChainName").Selected Then`

Comment: @EEM Thanks for that

Comment: @QHarr For some reason this throws an error for me, may be because my tables are in one sheet, whereas the slicer and the plots are in the other and I'm not referencing them correctly...
But thanks for mentioning about code location and adding worksheet references!

Comment: The worksheet names for the hide rows would be the sheet name where you want to hide. The code goes in the sheet where your pivottable is. You change Parent. for ActiveWorkbook maybe. You would update the pivottable name appropriately.